# How to run supertest in authenticated endpoints generated by the angular fullstack generator

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, supertest, angular-fullstack

I am trying to use supertest to test the behaivour of an authenticated enpoint that I made using the yeoman [angular full stack generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack). I tryed using the simple auth as described in the the supertests docs but I am still getting 404 errors.

The endpoint and the test are configured in the following way:

server/api/thing/index.js

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var auth = require('../../auth/auth.service');

var controller = require('./thing.controller');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.index);
module.exports = router;
```

fullstack-demo/server/api/thing/thing.spec.js

```
'use strict';

var should = require('should');
var app = require('../../app');
var request = require('supertest');
var User = require('./user.model');

describe('GET /api/things', function() {
  before(function(done) {
    //Create user for testing
    var user = new User({
      provider: 'local',
      name: 'Fake User',
      email: 'test@test.com',
      password: 'test'
    });
    user.save(function(){done()});
  });

  it('should respond with JSON array', function(done) {
    request(app)
      .get('/api/things')
      .auth('test@test.com', 'test')
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        res.body.should.be.instanceof(Array);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Any ideas on how to test this endpoint?

I think the errors might be related to the fact that I am using Passport for auth, is there any way to authenticate supertest against Passport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution! I just needed to path the auth token to the authenticated endpoint.

```
var server = request.agent('http://localhost:9000');
var token = null
describe('GET /api/things', function() {

  before(function(done){

    User.find({}).remove(function() {
      User.create({
        provider: 'local',
        name: 'Test User',
        email: 'test@test.com',
        password: 'test'
      }, {
        provider: 'local',
        role: 'admin',
        name: 'Admin',
        email: 'admin@admin.com',
        password: 'admin'
      }, function() {
          console.log('finished populating users');
          server.post('/auth/local')
            .send({email:'test@test.com', password:'test'})
            .expect(302)
            .end(function(err, res){
              console.error('ERROR ' + JSON.stringify(err));
              console.log('BODY ' + JSON.stringify(res.body));
              token = res.body.token;
              done();
            })
        }
      );
    });



  });

  it('should respond with JSON array', function(done) {
    server.get('/api/things')
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer '  + token)
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        res.body.should.be.instanceof(Array);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```